# Can't create a trigger into PHPMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, triggers, dml

I just want to create a trigger for my phpmyadmin. Basically the intended function is whenever I update a credit column of my finance table, the balance column will be automatically updated for each row.

My program is:

```
    CREATE TRIGGER UPDATE_BALANCE AFTER UPDATE financeofstudents
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
    IF financeofstudents.credit > 0 
    AND
    financeofstudents.credit <= financeofstudents.debit
    THEN
    UPDATE financeofstudents SET financeofstudents.balance = financeofstudents.debit-    financeofstudents.credit;
    END IF;
    END
```

but it gives me this error:

```
    Error

SQL query:

CREATE TRIGGER UPDATE_BALANCE AFTER UPDATE financeofstudents
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF financeofstudents.credit > 0 
AND
financeofstudents.credit <= financeofstudents.debit
THEN
UPDATE financeofstudents SET financeofstudents.balance = financeofstudents.debit-financeofstudents.credit

MySQL said: Documentation
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'financeofstudents
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF financeofstudents.credit > 0
AND
f' at line 1
```

I don't know where is the problem. Expert guys, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is a useful hint here.  It says **.. for the right syntax to use near `'some text from your query starting with the first thing it didn't understand'`**.

In your case, you need the word `ON` before the name of the table.

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_balance 
       AFTER UPDATE
       ON financeofstudents

FOR EACH ROW
```

If you observed that MySQL error messages are hard to interpret, you would be correct.